# Tomcat no jsp rendering without any error or exception

Tags: jsp, tomcat, firewall

Symptoms:

- Working webapp (works on other server)
- Has jsp / views.
- Response is empty (length: 0)
- No exception in the logs.
- Might take a while, while server responds.
- The log is not different from the working server's log

Answer (score 0):

After setting log details to highest (which resulted in ~30 Mb of log for just the startup):

```
*TIMESTAMP* | DEBUG | http-nio-*PORT*-exec-1 | org.apache.commons.digester.Digester:resolveEntity:1732 |  Trying to resolve using system ID 'http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd'
*TIMESTAMP* | DEBUG | http-nio-*PORT*-exec-1 | org.apache.commons.digester.Digester:resolveEntity:1745 |  Resolving to alternate DTD 'http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd'
```

Tomcat did not gave an exception, just a debug message about it, however resulted in failing rendering the view.
It might take a long time to load, if the firewall does not properly refuse the connection.

Reason:
Tomcat wants to go for the view definition file, but can't, the firewall rules blocks it.
Solutions:

### A.

Open the firewall for tiles.apache.org (warning, it might rolling IP!),

### B.

Or use local .dtd in views.xml files:

```
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configurations 1.1//EN" "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/tiles-config_1_1.dtd">
```

To

```
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions SYSTEM "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configurations 1.1//EN" "../dtds/tiles-config_1_1.dtd">
```

And include the dtd file with the webapp / WAR.
Don't forget to do this for all the views, with the appropriate local url.
This is a good, long term solution.